# $K$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^n,||.||)$ iff $K$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^n,||.||_2).$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $||.||$ be any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ and $K\subset\mathbb R^n.$ How to show that

Verify: $K$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^n,||.||)$ iff $K$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^n,||.||_2).$

I tried using the equivalence of two norms on a finite dimension NLS but couldn’t come to any conclusion.

Comment: Equivalence norms are actually the solution already. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can I use equivalence norm here? I think boundedness is not a topological property.

Comment: You can show, that both spaces are topological isomorphic, using the equivalence of norms.

Comment: Does  boundedness remains invariant under topological isomorphism?

Comment: Boundedness is only defined in a normed space, or metric space. Homeomorphisms only care about continuity, so the answer is no. For example $x\mapsto 1/x$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(1, +\infty)$.

Comment: Then how to use it to solve the question?

Comment: Can you write the equivalence of norms as a formula?

Comment: That means by using homeomorphism?

Comment: Ohh sorry I mean $c||x||\le||x||_2\le C||x||$ right?

Comment: Remark: this is not directly useful to you, but in ${\mathbb R}^n$, there is the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) that relates continuity and boundedness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the equivalence of norms mean that there are positive constants
$a$ and $b$ such that for all $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$,
$$a \|x\|\le \|x\|_2\le b\|x\|$$